# How to Discard One of the Line Segments?

Tags: opengl, shader

I'm using `GL_LINES` to draw lots of lines. But some of the lines should be hidden. Is there any way to discard a specific line segment?

I can implement this by putting lines in different buffers. However, the performance is bad when I have too many buffers. So currently I want to put them into a single buffer and discard the unnecessary one.

Comment: Oh, I think I can use a indice buffer to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: You should not use GL_LINES in modern GL, just as a note. To be more helpful, use degenerate indices: A line with i0==i1 will not draw. And not much bookkeeping needed!

Comment: in oldstyle api there was [glEdgeFlag](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEdgeFlag.xml) I think there should be something similar in the new api too

Comment: @starmole Oh, you mean I should use GL_LINES_STRIP and also use degenerate indices?

Comment: @starmole Seems it doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685516/degenerated-vertices-and-gl-line-strip

Answer (score -1):

There is a `discard` keyword in GLSL. You can use it in the `Fragment Stage` to discard pixels you don't want to render. Here is an example that discards all red pixels:

```
sampled_color = texture(tex_sampler, tex_coords_FS_in);//Can be any way of obtaining pixels
if(color.rgb == vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
{
    discard;
}
```

Comment: I don't thing this is helpful. If asker is using GL_LINES i doubt there are shaders involved?

Comment: @starmole this was the first and easiest solution that came to my mind, and I have already used `GL_LINES` together with shaders to change the position of the lines based on an attribute. I don't know what's wrong with my answer